# React Component SCSS available for all Components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I just started learning ReactJS and I made a Project with `.scss`

[image]

For some reason when I add a style in a `.scss` file that style also changes other components' styles as well.

example:
I add a ***li*** style in the Home.scss, but it will change the style of the Footer component's ***li*** too. I didn't import it into the Footer.js or anything.

Does anyone know what is the reason why does it do it, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `className` per component won't solve your problem, it will work as expected until you have any nested component.

Because if you add

```css
#component-name {
  li {
    ...
  }
}
```

The CSS will be applied to any component inside of that component too.

To limit your CSS to a component in react, you have a few options :

### CSS Modules

**Create React App** supports CSS Modules out of the box (as of version 2)
It works with SCSS too (`YourComponent.module.scss`)

`YourComponent.js`:

```js
import styles from './YourComponent.module.css'

export const YourComponent () => {
  <ul>
    <li className={styles.yourLi}>
  </ul>
}
```

`YourComponent.module.scss`:

```css
.yourLi {
  color: blue;
}
```

### CSS-in-JS

With this method, as the name suggests, you can declare your CSS within your JS.
There are multiple libraries to implement this.

##### [Styled-Components](https://styled-components.com/)

Here is an example with **styled components** which is the one that seems to be the most used as of today:

```js
const YourLi = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
`  

render(
  <div>
    <ul>
      <YourLi>
        Your styled li
      </YourLi>
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class footer in the first div of footer component

sass allows nested defining of classes like

```
.footer{
    li{
        }
    }
```

using that can help.
since it doesn't matter where you import scss in react. styles are imported globally by default.

Comment: You are right. However, it would be still nice if an Scss file would be used only if I import it to the particular .js file. It would be the usual web dev common sense.